# Union and Intersection of Collection of Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm attempting a problem:

Find $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty Ai$ and $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty Ai$, if for every positive integer $i$ $Ai=(0,i)$, that is, the set of real numbers $x$ with $0<x<i$.

I first start with $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty Ai$.

I know that when you expand it out, you'll get ${(0,1), (0,2), (0,3),...} $ which will keep continuing all the way to infinity. Since it is asking for the intersection of all the sets, it is asking for the set which has elements that are members of all the sets in the collection. Would the correct answer be $A_n = (0,Z^+) $, where $Z^+$ is the set of positive integers?

Now for $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty Ai$.

This is asking for the set which has elements that are members of at least one set in the collection. Since $i$ goes all the way up to infinity, isn't there an infinite possible amount of answers here? For example, one answer could be $(0,1)=A_{n_1}$. Or it could even be $A_{n_2} = (0,Z^+) $?

I think I have this right and am going about correctly. Or am I?

Comment: You're going in the opposite direction for intersections, Bob; intersections become smaller; notice that , e.g., $2$ is not in $(0,1)$, same for $3$, etc.

Comment: I see. So would the intersection be $A_n = (0,n),(0,n+1),(0,n+2),...$, where n starts at 1 and goes to $\infty$? If so I'm not sure how to write it as a single set.

Comment: Can you see that $(0,1)$ is in every set, and it is the only interval that is in every other set? Usually you need to give some argument to this effect.

Comment: Ah. Yes, I recognize that $(0,1)$ would be in every set. But so would $(0,2)$, and $(0,3)$...?

Comment: I'm interpreting it as a single set with members ${(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),...}$

Comment: No; how is $(0,2)$ contained in $(0,1)$? You're looking for the collection of elements that are in _every_ set. No point in $(1,2)$ as a subset of $(0,2)$ is contained in $(0,1)$.

Comment: I see. So wouldn't the set $(0,Z^+)$ be the intersection?

Comment: Or if that notation doesn't work where you use $Z^+$, it seems to me that it would be $0$ instead.

Comment: Let me post as an answer, to avoid too many comments, and then let me know if you have a followup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definition:
$A\cap B =\{x: x\in A \text{ and } x\in B\}$. That means any elements that belongs to $A\cap B$ must be in both $A$ and $B$. So

$\cap_{i=1}^{n}(0,i) =(0,1)$. As  $n\to \infty$, we have $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}(0,i) =(0,1)$.

On the other hand, $A\cup B =\{x: x\in A \text{ or } x\in B\}$. That means any elements that belongs to $A\cup B$ must be in either $A$ or $B$. So

$\cap_{i=1}^{n}(0,i) =(0,n)$. As  $n\to \infty$, we have $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}(0,i) =(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of a collection of sets consists of the elements that are in every one of the sets. One thing you may see is that the intersection of sets is not larger than the smallest of the sets ( when smallness applies, like in this case).

In this case, you want to find all Reals that are in *each* of :

$(0,1), (0,2),...., (0,n), (0, n+1),.....$

Now, can you see that, e.g., $2$, or $3$ will not be in every one of the sets?

Notice too, that these sets are nested, i.e., $(0,1)\subset (0,2) \subset (0,3) \subset....$

Does that help you see what the intersection set is ?

The union of sets , will contain all the elements that are in *at least* one of the sets, basically the elements that are in either $(0,1)$ or in $(0,2)$, or.....

Comment: It appears as though there is not one single set that has members present in all of the sets of the collection? Thus is would be 0 (empty set)?

Comment: Bingo--is not my name-o--you got it.

Comment: I don't believe that $(0,1)$ is in every set since $(0,1)$ $\neq$ $(0,2)$ (and so forth)

Comment: No; there not _equal_ to each other; one is _contained_ in the other, which is what the key issue is here.

Comment: So the intersection would be the null set.

As for the union, is there an infinite amount of possibilities? By definition it is the set that contains elements that are members of at least one set in the collection. So, it be $(0,1)$ or $(0,12938)$ for example?

Comment: No; the intersection is $(0,1)$, because $(0,1)$ is the largest set that is contained in all other sets; you can see this from the chain of inclusions.

Comment: Is my definition of union correct?

Comment: The reason I ask is because it suggests that the union could be pretty much anything.

Comment: Yes, the union is everything.

Comment: So why can't the union of the collection of sets be $(0,12121)$ for example?

Comment: Please see the answer post.

Comment: They are not subsets of each other though?

Comment: One last: Sorry, Bob, it seems we're not getting anywhere; I'll let someone else help you, hope they can do a better job than I. good luck.